# SPFile "Content Type ID" is default even after changing programmatically when excel has macros

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, contenttype, spfile

Below is the code used to update the content type of an spfile.

newFile.Item["Content Type ID"] = spWeb.ContentTypes["Subject Attachment"].Id;
newFile.Item.Update();

but "Content Type ID" for the attachment file is assigned **default** value when the excel file has the **macro**.

How do i change the code such that it does not take the default "Content Type ID" when excel file has macro.

**NOTE**: This behavior is observed only when attachment file has macro.